# Python: executable not running correctly

Tags: python, tkinter, exe, pyinstaller

What is the correct command of `pyinstaller` to successfully build `.exe` file from python project.

I've tried below commands but not working in my case.

```
Project
|--->main.py
|--->second.py
|--->images (folder)
      |--->image.jpg
```

Above is my project structure. I have given `main.py` to `pyinstaller` command.

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir "main.py" --console --log-level "DEBUG" --add-data "images/image.jpg;." --add-data "second.py;."
```

Exe is generated from above line and also runs but when it calls second.py it shows error that `modules not found`. As both python files uses same modules.

I've also tried using `virtualenv` and given path of it.

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir "main.py" --console --log-level "DEBUG" --add-data "images/image.jpg;." --add-data "second.py;." --paths "venv/Lib/site-packages" --paths "venv/Lib"
```

This don't even run exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove --add-data "second.py;." from your build command. If your second.py script is imported in your main than pyinstaller will find it. --add-data is for data, not program.

Comment: I have not imported second.py in main.py

Comment: if your two scripts are not interacting (one using the other) than you have to build two exe.